# Query to Retrieve Record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two forms: Customers and Invoices.
What I want is when I click on the ID field in Invoices form, a search message will appear to enter the customer name (or part of it) and then a list will appear with the customers name to choose from, after choosing the name, the other fields in Invoices form will be retrieved from Customers form
So how can I do it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Try to make it work and we will help you if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Below is full code to retreive data from dataaccess database.

```
 using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("**connectionstring**"))  
{  
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SHAPE {SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers} " +  
  "APPEND ({SELECT CustomerID, OrderID FROM Orders} AS Orders " +  
  "RELATE CustomerID TO CustomerID)", connection);  

DataSet customers = new DataSet();  
adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");  
}
```

Comment: That SQL syntax is very far from Access SQL.